# React invalidate client's cache

Tags: reactjs, nginx, caching

How can I have the cache be invalidated for clients if the current build of my react project is different than the one they're on?

When I push a new build, they always attempt to use a cached version, so it doesn't show any of the changes.

If it means anything I'm hosting it with nginx.

Answer (score 0):

**It's not react related problem.**

Use any method used earlier with html to force browser cache refresh - new (every build/update changed) `bundleRandomNumberedName.js`, random or version related url parameters (`'bundle.js?rev=1.2.3'`) ... google for it?